# Enable copy/paste in vim on bare Linux

Tags: linux, vim, clipboard

I'm using vim on Linux Debian without desktop environment (i.e xorg, i3, urxvt). I'm not unable to copy and paste ("+, "* not work), because *clipboard* package is not installed:

```
└> vim --version | grep clipboard
-clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +vartabs
+eval              +mouse_gpm         +syntax            -xterm_clipboard
```

What should I install to enable *clipboard*?

#### --- upd:

I'm running X server

Comment: Which `vim` package have you installed?

Comment: `
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jun 15 2019 16:41:15)
Included patches: 1-875, 878, 884, 948, 1046, 1365-1368, 1382, 1401
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.
`

Comment: Vim isn't responsible for copy/past behavior in that configuration, `urxvt` is: [Copying & Pasting with URxvt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212360/copying-pasting-with-urxvt)

Comment: How are you expecting to use the X selections of an X server if you aren't running an X server?

Comment: I'm running xorg. I can use _ctrl-alt-v_ to copy/paste in _urxvt_ and _vim_. But "+, "* not work

Comment: Note then that "without desktop environment (i.e xorg" can be read as your _not_ running an X server.

Comment: Ok, I will update this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13564/why-is-vim-for-debian-compiled-without-clipboard), you will need to install `vim-gtk`. The package includes a non-gui version but will install a bunch of dependencies.

Comment: How are you expecting a VIM that has no X client code to access the X clipboard of an X server?  (-:

Comment: Oops, I thought that vim-nox would include a way to use the clipboard but it won't as far as I can tell.

Comment: `vim-gtk` works well, but I would prefer approach without bunch of dependencies to achieve that